# Prove Pascal's Rule Algebraically

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I am trying to prove Pascal's Rule algebraically but I'm stuck on simplifying the numerator. This is the last step that I have, but I'm not sure where to go from here

$$=\frac{\left[(k-1)(n-k)!+k(n-1-k)!\right]\times(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: You can find it here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule#Algebraic_proof

Comment: Algebraic proof can also be found in answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253514).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will assume that you are trying to show that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, where $n$ and $k$ are each $\ge 1$. Expressing the right-hand side in terms of factorials, we get
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}.$$
We want to bring the above expression to a common denominator. So we multiply top and bottom of the first term by $n-k$, and top and bottom of the second term by $k$. We get
$$\frac{(n-1)!(n-k)+(n-1)!k}{k!(n-k)!}.$$
The bottom now looks nice. The two terms on top have a common factor of $(n-1)!$. So the top can be rewritten as
$$(n-1)![(n-k)+k)],$$ 
which is $(n-1)!n$, that is, $n!$. Thus we end up with $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, which is $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Why wouldn't you multiply the first term by (k-1)!(n-k)!?

Comment: @Susan You can exploit the factorial
$$k! = \prod_{j=1}^k j$$
So $(n-k-1)! \cdot (n-k) = (n-k)!$ and $(k-1)! \cdot k = k!$

Comment: @Susan: We **could** multiply top and bottom of the first term as you suggest, and do something similar with the second term. We then end up with a common denominator that is much larger than necessary, but that's OK. We also end up with a more complicated expression on top. That *can* be simplified, and after simplification we can do a lot of cancelling of common stuff from top and bottom. It is just a lot messier. Also, I had an eye on the ultimate answer, which has a $k!(n-k)!$ at the bottom. So that's a nice common denominator to aim for, and it is achievable.